# Filter out outstanding error records from table of measures

Tags: sql, statistics

I have a table which stores distance covered by some vehicle

```
VEH_ID  DATE                    DISTANCE
1      2018-07-16 12:04:03.000  439025
1      2018-07-16 12:04:33.000  439026
1      2018-07-16 12:05:03.000  439026
1      2018-07-16 12:05:33.000  439027
```

I want to count distance covered in some period of time. Seems simple - do MAX(DISTANCE)-MIN(DISTANCE) in the given record's range. Or last record distance - first record distance.

My problem is that about 1%-4% (depending on substet of records) of records are totally wrong. They are some measurement errors coming from the device. So my data actually look like:

```
VEH_ID  DATE                     DISTANCE
1       2018-07-16 12:04:03.000  439025
1       2018-07-16 12:04:33.000  7
1       2018-07-16 12:05:03.000  439026
1       2018-07-16 12:05:33.000  439027
```

IF I use MAX and MIN, sql finds these records and my calculations become totally wrong. It may also happen that first/last record will contain the error.

I suppose I need to filter out these wrong records somehow where making my calculations. I suppose also that 100% perfect algorithm doesn't exist but something working in 95% of cases would be still good.

Any advice how to count my covered distance and ignore the blunders during that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If a value is less than the predecessor or greater than the successor, then you can filter it out:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             lag(distance) over (partition by veh_id order by date) as prev_distance,
             lead(distance) over (partition by veh_id order by date) as next_distance
      from distances d
     ) d
where prev_distance > distance or distance > next_distance;
```

This is not 100% accurate.  It also assumes that the anomalies are isolated -- which is probably a bad assumption.  But it might work for your problem.